# How to know when image is loaded in imageview in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am fetching image from Documents directory in UIImageView.

I want that after loading image I want to start timer after image is loaded in ImageView.

How do I know that image is loaded completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UIImageView's image is "loaded" by the time `setImage:` or `initWithImage:` returns. There is no way provided by the class to load it asynchronously.

Comment: It works fine with simulator, but when I try it in device the timer runs faster when second image is loaded.  What can be done?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the timer runs faster"? Are you loading the same image a second time? If so, it could be cached.

Comment: @Meghan: Is the timer running faster, or are you creating a second timer without invalidating the first and thinking it is the second firing when it is really the first?

Comment: @jessecurry : I am loading other image second time.

Comment: I am invalidating timer on button press or after 5 seconds whichever is earlier.